# What does mean : UnreadablePostError: timeout during read(23062) on wsgi.input?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have a Django 1.7 application hosted with uwsgi and I am getting randomly this kind of errors. What does it means?

I have this stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace (most recent call last):

  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "mobile_backend/views.py", line 162, in event_location_view
    events = json.loads(request.body)
  File "django/http/request.py", line 208, in body
    six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "django/http/request.py", line 206, in body
    self._body = self.read()
  File "django/http/request.py", line 267, in read
    six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "django/http/request.py", line 265, in read
    return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 53, in read
    result = self.buffer + self._read_limited()
  File "django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 47, in _read_limited
    result = self.stream.read(size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading:

- http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2015-June/008073.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#django.http.UnreadablePostError

It seems that it happens when the client drops the connection.